# Twilio test response includes full TwiML/xml

Tags: asp.net-core, twilio

I set up a webhook to a rest API on my server. When I send a message to the test twilio number and get the full XML/TwiML response back.

```
Sent from your Twilio trial account - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
<Message>Hello World</Message>
</Response>
```

Is this because it's a test number or am I messing something up on the server? I'm using .net core which doesn't seem to have any support compared to .net standard.

My thought is the response should be

```
Sent from your Twilio trial account - Hello World
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is a guess, but I think you may be returning the response with a mime type of `text/plain`. If you set the `Content-Type` header of your response to `text/xml` you should just see the text in the response.

Comment: Thanks, good start I see text/plain in my headers. I'll see if I can change that.

Comment: is there a list of headers sent by the webhook api? Does it send {"Accept":"application/xml"}?

Comment: It actually accepts `text/plain` and will automatically respond with the text in the response, which is why in this case you're seeing the whole of your XML in the response text.

Comment: That was it! Thanks @philnash. I forced the response to be text/xml and it worked.